# Update Custom Theme Version

Tags: theme-development

What seems to be a straightforward operation has me a little confused.

How do I push my updated changes to a custom theme to my wordpress instance?

I.e., I create a custom theme > upload it to my wordpress site > make changes to the same theme in my local environment and update `version` in `style.css`.

From here, how do I get wordpress to register the updated version? I tried reuploading the new archive file, but it comes through as a new theme in the admin panel. Seems wonky to me. What's the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: If you don't use a repo - such as github - or the theme is not hosted by wordpress.org - there is not additional step - as I presume you use FTP to upload files..

Comment: @QStudio I compress the files into an archive and I upload the theme from the themes panel in the admin. I do not use FTP.

Comment: If you upload a theme, WP might expect it to be new - and, you might as well just be uploading it via FTP - an alternative route is to use a 3rd party host, like GitHub, then you can also use Git to version files locally, push to a public or private repo, make releases on GH and use a plugin like GitHub Updater to help manage versions across your installs.

Comment: Are you able to FTP?